# Cannot find Makefile. Check your build settings

Tags: macos, qt

- Compilers: I added appropriate compiler
- Qt Versions: I added appropriate qt version
- Kits: I added appropriate kit and set it correctly

I also added environment, but when I try 'Start Debugging' in Compile Output I get :

```
  13:36:22: Cannot find Makefile. Check your build settings.
  Error while building/deploying project Tests (kit: Desktop Qt 4.8.6 
  x86 
  (qt48-10.7))
  When executing step "Make"
  13:36:22: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

How can I fix it, sorry that so a little information but it all that I have

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using Qt Creator?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your project's build settings? I would assume that the `Makefile` is generated but lands somewhere outside the directory where the build artifacts are created.

Comment: qmake generates makefiles.

Comment: @KYL3R Obviously, but this doesn't help if the IDE is not setup correctly. ;)

Comment: Maybe you need a proper .pro file

Comment: Are you using Qt Creator?  - Yes, I was looking for a make file in the build  directory but it is not there

Comment: Are you using `pro` project file or `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: I am using a pro-file

Comment: Can you try running `qmake` from the terminal to ensure that it isn't an IDE configuration problem?

Comment: I already do this and everything is fine, a few seconds ago I deleted all project and qt and some dependencies, and installed it all again and now everything is fine, I dont know why, but now I get a new error : clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]